How to setup AWS Realtime audio translation (AWS transcribe stream) with Real application
I want to know how to connect aws  transcribe stream with react application. because I want to get Realtime translation. I'm using the microphone-stream library to capture audio from the user's microphone and the AWS SDK to send this audio to the Transcribe Streaming service. Here i tried with aws-sdk and added WebSocket. but it not getting any output
I have tried following the instructions.
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { TranscribeStreamingClient, StartStreamTranscriptionCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-transcribe-streaming';

interface TranscriptResult {
    Alternatives: { Items: { Content: string }[] }[];
}

const TranscriptionComponent: React.FC = () => {
    const [transcript, setTranscript] = useState<string>('');
    const [isRecording, setIsRecording] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

    const mediaRecorderRef = useRef<MediaRecorder | null>(null);
    const clientRef = useRef<TranscribeStreamingClient | null>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        clientRef.current = new TranscribeStreamingClient({
            region: AWS region',
            credentials: {
                accessKeyId: 'IAM access Key',
                secretAccessKey: 'IAM secret key',
            },
        });

        return () => {
            stopRecording();
        };
    }, []);

    const startRecording = async () => {
        try {
            const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
            const mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            mediaRecorderRef.current = mediaRecorder;
            const audioChunks: Blob[] = [];

            mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
                audioChunks.push(event.data);
            };

            mediaRecorder.onstop = async () => {
                const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/pcm' });
                const arrayBuffer = await audioBlob.arrayBuffer();
                const audioChunk = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);

                // Prepare the audioStream as required by AWS Transcribe
                const audioStream = (async function* () {
                    yield { AudioEvent: { AudioChunk: audioChunk } };
                })();

                const command = new StartStreamTranscriptionCommand({
                    LanguageCode: 'en-US',
                    MediaEncoding: 'pcm',
                    MediaSampleRateHertz: 44100,
                    AudioStream: audioStream,
                });

                const client = clientRef.current;
                if (client) {
                    setIsRecording(true);
                    setError(null);

                    try {
                        const response = await client.send(command);
                        console.log('Transcription response:', response);
                        handleResponse(response);
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.error('Error sending transcription request:', err);
                        setError('Error sending transcription request.');
                    }
                }
            };

            mediaRecorder.start();
            setIsRecording(true);

        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error accessing microphone:', err);
            setError('Failed to access the microphone. Please check your permissions.');
        }
    };

    const handleResponse = async (response: any) => {
        console.log("im")
        try {
            for await (const event of response.TranscriptResultStream) {
                if (event.TranscriptEvent) {
                    const results: TranscriptResult[] = event.TranscriptEvent.Transcript.Results;
                    results.forEach((result) => {
                        result.Alternatives.forEach((alternative) => {
                            const transcript = alternative.Items.map((item) => item.Content).join(' ');
                            setTranscript((prev) => `${prev} ${transcript}`);
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error handling transcription response:', err);
            setError('Error processing transcription response.');
        } finally {
            stopRecording();
        }
    };

    const stopRecording = () => {
        if (mediaRecorderRef.current) {
            mediaRecorderRef.current.stop();
            mediaRecorderRef.current = null;
        }
        setIsRecording(false);
    };

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1>AWS Transcribe</h1>
            <hr />
            {error && <div id="error" className="isa_error">{error}</div>}
            <textarea
                id="transcript"
                placeholder="Press Start and speak into your mic"
                rows={5}
                readOnly
                value={transcript}
            ></textarea>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col">
                    <button
                        id="start-button"
                        className="button-xl"
                        title="Start Transcription"
                        onClick={startRecording}
                        disabled={isRecording}
                    >
                        <i className="fa fa-microphone"></i> Start
                    </button>
                    <button
                        id="stop-button"
                        className="button-xl"
                        title="Stop Transcription"
                        onClick={stopRecording}
                        disabled={!isRecording}
                    >
                        <i className="fa fa-stop-circle"></i> Stop
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default TranscriptionComponent;


